# Is it correct to use "respected" to salute in formal written English?

Tags: forms-of-address

Is it correct to use **Respected** to salute in formal written English?. For instance:

**Respected** Suan Scholarship Committee

Comment: You've got two unrelated questions here, and neither show any context or research. Can you check that the questions are on-topic for this site, and if so, log them separately.

Comment: It is grammatical. It is comprehensible. But if you address somebody as "respected" - in any context, as far as I can think, but certainly in a letter or similar - you mark yourself as not being a native English speaker.

Comment: I don't understand your second question: there are no hyphens. But in any case _Agricultural and farming's program_ is not idiomatic English. And _Dear_ followed by a department or office or program is not idiomatic English (it is still used in letters, though rarely in electronic communication by native English speakers, but it is always addressed to an individual, or individuals).

Comment: @ColinFine To your first comment: What other word do you think shows the same respect as *respected* but sounds more like a natural English speaker?. To your second comment: the question was updated since I made a mistake. On the other hand, what words could you suggest to address to a program or committee?, preferably those that show respect or can be quite formal.

Comment: You should use the official name of the organisation; you can't change _Farming_ to _Crop_ at random! Is there really an apostrophe in the official name? At one time I would have recommended _Dear Sirs_, but I'm sure that would be frowned on as non-inclusive today.

Comment: I will edit to remove the second question.  That can be asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments,  "Respected ..." is grammatical and understandable, but not common in English.

As a salutation in a letter:

The best option is to address the chair of the committee

> Dear Professor Smith,

If that's not possible, then address the people on the committee

> Dear members of the Suan Scholarship Committee,

(it is also common to combine these as:

> Dear Professor Smith and members of the Suan Scholarship Committee,

Culturally, the assumption is that respect must be earned, but if it is earned it will be assumed. People won't think you don't give them the respect they are due if you omit terms like "respected".  And as a result, such terms are almost never used.  The same level of respect is indicated by

- not using words like "respected"
- getting to the point,
- keeping it formal,
- and avoiding flowery writing.